# Regular expression to validate currency field which can have comma and null

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am new to Jquery and Regular expression. I have 2 text filed. one is currency and other one is date time.
I need two separate Regular expression to validate each.

the currency formats

```
null(empty)
0-999999999
0.00-999999999.99
0-999,999,999
0.00-999,999,999.99
```

the date time formats

```
2014-11-17 23:45
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried for date ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$

Comment: Can you be very specific on the validation you need ? Example: `^[\d.,-]+$` is for currency, `^[\d :-]+$` is for time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better not to use regex for matching integer range. But incase if you really need it try below regex.

Regex for matching date

```
^\d{4}-((?=0)(0[1-9])|(?=1)(1[012]))-((?=[0])(0[1-9])|(?=[12])(\d{2})|(?=[3])(3[01]))\s+([01]\d|(?=2)(2[0-3])):([012345]\d)$
```

Regex to match currency range

```
^(:?(?=[^0])(\d{1,3},?){1,3}|0)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Check it out [here](http://regex101.com/r/gK7lQ4/2)

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik thanks for pointing out, I have updated it with new regex which would validate ranges of month, year, day, hours, minutes and seconds. But one thing to remember is as I have mentioned for currency range, regex are not meant to validate they are here to match strings.

Comment: thank you for your reply. the currency is not working for null(empty) value

Comment: Yes the pattern will not match empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

**for date time & Currency:**

```html
Date:<input type="text" pattern="^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]) ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"   />


Currency:<input type="text" pattern="^(?(?!0)(\d{1,3},?){1,3}|0)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"   />
```

Comment: The date regex will not match months other than 01,02,11,12  and the 60th minute in hours.

Comment: @Kannan Mohan i do not understand.. because 60th minute is not true. it will be (00-59)=60.

Comment: missed it, in that case others has to be matched.

Comment: i never see that (12:60).

Comment: @ Kannan Mohan thanks, for checking my answer. i think have to remove 60 minute option in your answer, then your answer may be better.

Comment: `pattern` attributes should not be wrapped with `^$`, I think

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples

Date Time:  `^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{,12}[ ]\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$`

Currency:  `^(?:null|\d(?:\.\d{2})?-(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{2})?)$`

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      null
   |  
      \d     
      (?: \. \d{2} )?
      -
      (?:
           \d{1,3} 
           (?: , \d{3} )*
        |  
           \d+ 
      )
      (?: \. \d{2} )?
 )
 $
```